# Approximating multi-variate continuous functions that map to [0,1] by polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, polynomials, reference-request, approximation-theory

The [Stone-Weierstrass Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) says that the polynomials are dense in C[X] under the sup norm, where X is any Hausdorff space. There have been several previous posts asking about approximations of $f \in C[X]$ with polynomials

$P_n = \{p | p $ is a polynomial of degree less than or equal to $n\}$

for a fixed degree $n$. It seems like this is a problem that has certain bounds for $\inf_{p \in P_n} ||f - p||_\infty < \epsilon(n)$, where $\epsilon(n)$ is on the order $O(1/n)$ ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2295958/how-well-can-continuous-functions-on-0-1-be-approximated-by-polynomials-up-t?noredirect=1&lq=1),[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271013/approximating-continuous-functions-with-polynomials?noredirect=1&lq=1))

I have two questions:

1. If we restrict the output of $f: [-a, b] \rightarrow [0,1]$, are there any tighter bounds that can be said? Clearly, $\inf_{p \in P_n} ||f - p||_\infty < 1/2$ for the trivial case $p=1/2$.
2. Can we prove the same bounds for $f: [-a, b]^n -> \mathbb{R}$ and a multi-variate polynomial $P(x_1, ... x_n)$ as we did in the one-dimensional case? What if we restrict the range to $f: [-a, b]^n -> [0,1]$?

I am not sure how one would go about the first question, other than to note that $f$ is 1-Lipshitz and by the above posts there are potentially some tighter bounds there for Lipschitz functions. For the second question, I showed that the polynomials are still dense in $C[X]$, which makes me think there might be an analgous way to prove the error bounds as well?

This is probably all well-understood, but I'm not well-read on approximation theory. Any guidance would be wonderful.

Comment: Note that $X$ has to be a ***compact*** Hausdorff space for Stone-Weierstrass.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't state that originally, but the setting of the questions are in compact spaces.